# Egg whites in Crème Anglaise

Tags: eggs, egg-whites

I have seen different recipes for *Crème anglaise*. Some use only yolks, others uses whole eggs with white.

I usually like this "eggy" taste which may comes from the egg whites, but I would like to know which should be the proper way to make crème anglaise.

Answer (score 2):

The [*proper* way](https://cuisine.larousse.fr/recette/creme-anglaise) (French Larousse Culinaire reference) is to use only egg yolks.

But like everything else in cuisine recipes, whatever you like is good enough.

Comment: Not in french Cuisine, there are traditions we must understand.